# entity framework 5 code first unit testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm using c# entity framework 5 code first

All's going well until I started unit testing the code and I think they are related to the database migration.

No matter what I try entity either complains about the database model now being different (which it isn't), or it complains that it cannot find certain objects/models.

I'm using table attributes to map the models, and the unit tests seem to be ignoring that fact and trying to construct the sql using the original model name rather than the table name I have given it.

Result Message:

> Test method AllWales.Tests.Seeding_test.Test_County_Seed_is_22 threw
>   exception:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot find the object
>   "dbo.AccommodationModels" because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permissions.

AccommodationModel is the original class name, however I'm using table attributes:

```
[Table("Accommodations")]
public class AccommodationModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string PropertyReference { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

etc
etc

my DBContext

```
public class AllWalesDbContext : DbContext
{
    static AllWalesDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AllWalesDbContext, Configuration>());
    }

    public AllWalesDbContext():base("AllWalesDbContext") {}
```

etc
etc

I've also tried

```
    static AllWalesDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AllWalesDbContext>(null);
    }
```

All the other code works well except the Unit testing projects that are using the entity

My unit test

```
[TestClass()]
public class Seeding_test
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void Test_County_Seed_is_22()
    {

        int expected = 22;
        int actual = 0;

        using (var context = new AllWalesDbContext())
        {
            actual = context.County.Count();
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Banging my head against the wall on this for a couple of days now.

Comment: Does your unit test project have the correct connection string?

Comment: My main project has a connection string. I haven't put a separate one in the test project. Do I need one?

Comment: Try. You'll be surprised!

Comment: Good call Gert. That led me onto the solution.  There was a bunch of settings I needed to copy over for roles and providers, connection string, plus adding missing references. :-)